# What byte[] must have in order to be "savable" into bitmap?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'd want to save that byte[] into Bitmap, but it throws that `parameter is not valid`at `new Bitmap(ms)` why? what requirements does it have?

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 1 };
Bitmap bmp;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
    bmp.Save(@"C:\bit.bmp");
}
```

Comment: Hardly that sequence of bytes could be considered a bitmap. [BMP file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)

Comment: That's probably what I needed :P thanks